# Matlab interp1 curve doesn't follow data

Tags: matlab, plot, interpolation

I've been using interp1 to plot curves to follow sets of datapoints, and for most of the datapoints it's been working:

[image]

But when I try it with another set of datapoints it doesn't follow them at all:

[image]

For both interpolations the code I'm using is just:

```
curve = interp1(x, y, 'pchip');
```

Where x is just a set of numbers that correspond to the x axis of each datapoint, and y is the values themselves.

I can't tell what is different about the second dataset that is causing the interp1 function to not follow the data.

Comment: Well we certainly can't tell since you have posted no information about the data what so ever.

Comment: Post code that reproduces the problem!

Comment: But also, shouldn't the third argument of `interp1` be your `xq` values, i.e. the `x` axis points that you want to interpolate at...

Comment: @Hoki Do you mean `1:size(x,1)`? Otherwise it will just produce a single point... but also from the docs I think if you leave it out but specify a method then you are (unintuitavely) using this form `vq = interp1(v,xq,method)` which means that the OP has `x` and `y` switched

Comment: @dan. you're totally right, it is `x` which is assumed in this form (and not `xq` as I said). I'll delete my wrong comment (yes I meant `1:size(x,1)` by the way, that was just a typo).

Comment: @Dan, the curves in the first graph had x = 1:32. There's no quick way to explain how I got the y values, but they're essentially the outputs of a number of biological modelling scripts, as are the y values for the second plot. For the second plot x = -90:10:90.

Comment: @Dan, the y values for the blue curve in the first graph are `[0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0003    0.1031   16.6713  116.7598  222.8781  320.5745  432.9076 588.1256  730.1581  868.4814  931.9780  671.5041  937.0615  884.6094  837.9061  801.1684  610.5040  590.3445 484.1824  322.8633  285.1995  193.3096   34.9518    0.3258    0.0012    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000]`.

Comment: @Dan, the y values for the second graph are `[0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0001   93.7013  476.6203  872.3159  671.5041  872.3159 476.6203   93.7013    0.0001    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000]`.

Comment: cannot reproduce: [code](http://pastebin.com/zU0hSsbC) and [plot output](http://i.imgur.com/njrR4Yc.png)

Comment: @m.s. I've had a look at your code and I think I understand now why I'm getting a non-accurate interpolation compared to your code, I've posted the answer below. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with thanks to @m.s. for providing his code, it turns out the issue is that with the second graph I was interpolating with x= -90:10:90, whereas if I interpolate with 1:19, in a similar manner to the first graph, then the problem is fixed.